# Bind rope-auto-import to a keyboard shortcut in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, rope

The way I know to auto-import using rope is to move my cursor to the name I want to import and do `M-x rope-auto-import`. I'd like to bind `rope-auto-import` to a keyboard shortcut to make this faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

1. Add the following line to my `.emacs` file:
   `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") 'rope-auto-import)`
2. `M-x load-file RET ~/.emacs RET`